# Filter Kubernetes API by pod name

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, kubernetes-apiserver

I have a Kubernetes cluster running in minikube, I want to filter out all Logstash pods via Kubernetes API. Kubernetes API documentation is a bit confusing, I did some research and found out that I can use something like this, but I have been unsuccessful so far:

```
localhost:8000/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?labelSelector=logstash
```

any ideas how to retrieve this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> any ideas how to retrieve this?

Since labels are defined in `<name>=<value>` pairs you need to supply both, as described in [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) (see the `API` section)

As an example, supposing you have:

- namepace: default
- labels on pods you want to select:

  - role=ops
  - application=logstash
- kubectl proxy runs on localhost:8000

Then your api call would look like this:

```
curl localhost:8000/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?labelSelector=role%3Dops,application%3Dlogstash
```

Comment: hmm brings back empty list!

Comment: In the example there are two labels to ilustrate multiple labels, you tried with your label/port/host?